# Count number of ways that sequences contain at least one of the given subsequences

Tags: python, combinatorics

Peter loves dices and some special numbers. Therefore he thrown dice n times and concatenate the numbers. Compute the probability that if he throws 6 to 27 seven times dice and concatenate the numbers, the sequence contains at least one subsequence of number sequence

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3
4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

I saw that there is a way to do it by Markov chains. Is there any way to write the code more elegantly, like using inclusion-exclusion principle?

My code that uses Markov chains:

```
from sets import Set

def matMul(a,b):
    zip_b = zip(*b)
    return [[sum(ele_a*ele_b for ele_a, ele_b in zip(row_a, col_b)) 
             for col_b in zip_b] for row_a in a]

"""Matrix power for positive integer power"""
def matPow(a, n):
    if n<1: return None
    if n==1: return a

    if n%2==0:
        aToHalfN = matPow(a, n/2)
        return matMul(aToHalfN, aToHalfN)
    else:
        return matMul(matPow(a, n-1), a)



def getProbSomeSeqIsSub(symbols, seqs, n, exactRational=False):

    def cleanSeqs(arr):
        ret = list(arr)
        changed = True
        while changed:
            changed = False
            for x in ret:
                hadADelete = False
                for y in ret:
                    if x!=y and y in x:
                        ret.remove(x)
                        hadADelete = True
                        changed = True
                        break
                if hadADelete:
                    break
        return ret


    seqs = cleanSeqs(seqs)

    symbolsLen = len(symbols)
    prefixes = Set([""]) #first state is '' empty start state

    for seq in seqs:
        for i in xrange(1, len(seq)):
            prefixes.add(seq[0:i])

    prefixes = sorted(list(prefixes))
    M = len(prefixes)+1 #last state (index M-1) is the absorbing one

    def findFallsBackTo(appendedRun):
        for i in xrange(0,len(appendedRun)):
            if appendedRun[i:] in prefixes:
                return appendedRun[i:]
        return ""

    def incrState(stateDict, state):
        if state in stateDict:
            stateDict[state] += 1
        else:
            stateDict[state] = 1

    def someEndInSeqs(s):
        for i in xrange(len(s)):
            if s[i:] in seqs: return True
        return False

    def getToStateVals(stateStr):
        ret = {}
        for i in symbols:
            stPlusI = stateStr+str(i)
            if someEndInSeqs(stPlusI):
                incrState(ret, M-1)
            elif stPlusI in prefixes:
                incrState( ret, prefixes.index(stPlusI) )
            else:
                fallsToPrefix = findFallsBackTo(stPlusI)
                incrState(ret, prefixes.index(fallsToPrefix))
        return ret    


    a = []
    aInts = []
    for i in xrange(M):
        a += [[]]
        aInts += [[]]
        for j in xrange(M):
            a[i] += [0]
            aInts[i] += [0]

    for i in xrange(M-1):
        ps = getToStateVals(prefixes[i])
        for toI in ps:
            a[toI][i] = float(ps[toI])/symbolsLen
            aInts[toI][i] = ps[toI]

    a[M-1][M-1] = 1.0
    aInts[M-1][M-1] = symbolsLen

    if exactRational: return str(matPow(aInts, n)[M-1][0])+" / "+str(symbolsLen**n)
    else: return matPow(a, n)[M-1][0]



for i in range(6,28):
 a = getProbSomeSeqIsSub([1,2,3,4,5,6], ["123456", "112233", "445566",  "111222", "333444", '555666', '111111', '222222', '333333', '444444',  '555555', '666666'], i, True)

 b = a.split("/")
 oso = int(b[0])
 nimi = int(b[1])
 print(str(i)+ " "+str(oso*6**i/nimi))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use numpy!

Don't roll your own `matMul`. It's not worth it. `numpy` will outperform you and will be simpler to use. The same goes for `matPow`, though (I'm not sure) you may still need to write a thin wrapper around numpy.

### Python names

Use snake_case for functions and variables, such as

`get_sub_prob`

### Make a `main` function

...to pull your last six lines out of global scope.